# why python is not saving file with header for pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import os
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\bingo\Downloads\MarketP_28092018.txt")

df = df.iloc[:,0]
df.columns = ['Code']
df.columns
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\zeesu\Downloads\final.txt",   index=False , header = True)
```

When I am trying to save file to my local machine it not saving file with header. I tried various option but still it doesn't work.

It just saving data without any header...

Comment: not quite sure what you're trying do with the `iloc` there.... what does the `df.columns` show you from the `pd.read_csv(...)`?

Comment: iloc i am trying to fetch first column. df.columns dont show me anything

Comment: Does the CSV itself have column headers?

Comment: no it dont.i add header with df.columns = ['Code']

Comment: Try run this `pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]}).to_csv("a.txt", index=False)`. If it works, I think you have a problem with your df and you should share an example of your DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Since the output of `df.iloc[:,0]` is one column, it returns a pandas Series. A series doesn't contain field `columns`. Basically you need to convert a Series to a DataFrame.

There is also another problem. Since the file doesn't contain a header, the first row will be treated as a header. Here's how you can fix these two problems:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\bingo\Downloads\MarketP_28092018.txt", header=None)
# make sure you use header=None

df = df.iloc[:,0].to_frame()  # make sure you convert to DataFrame
df.columns = ['Code']
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\zeesu\Downloads\final.txt", index=False)
```

Comment: `df.iloc[:, [0] ]` also returns a frame.